# Best ways to configure nginx to serve yeoman angular generator files?

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, amazon-ec2, yeoman-generator-angular

I am quite new to configuring production servers to serve UI. I always wrote my code and someone else did the deployment. But I wish to move to the next stage now. Having said that, I wrote my UI code starting from yeoman-angular-generator and I wish to deploy it on my production Amazon ec2 instance.

I configured nginx on the instance and setup route53 and I am able to serve default 'Welcome to nginx' page from mydomain.com. What I wish to do is to serve my UI from mydomain.com. I tried to write a server block with location '/' pointing to my index.html from my dist folder. But it is not working.

Comment: Asking for best (anything) is almost always off topic for stackoverflow as it is just another way of asking for opinions.

Comment: @KevinB: Duly noted. rephrased question to be more specific

Comment: Are you using nginx for your webserver, or do you have a node backend.

Comment: nginx as a webserver. Backend is sqlalchemy/tornado/postgres. The APIs are RESTful

Comment: In that case you need two things: A server block serving static html files from your dist folder, and a rewrite that rewrites all requests to paths that don't exist back to index.html. I haven't set one of these up myself, so i'll just direct you to the documentation. http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample

Answer (score -1):

I usually set up something like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name your.project.com 
   location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html;
       root /path/to/project/dist/;
   }
}
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment?  What's wrong with it?  I use this for quite a few sites built using yeoman-angular-generator.